# Auto clear default text in a TEdit

Tags: delphi-7, default-value, editbox

I have a few TEdits on my form. When created they have default text in a gray font color. (e.g. "Surname" and "Name") See example below:

[image]

Their on click events causes the default text to  be cleared and their font color to be set to black.

[image]

My Problem: When I use the tab key to switch between the TEdits the onClick event will not triggered so the TEdit will not be cleared and the font color will stay grey.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this will be appreciated!

Comment: Check the onEnter event.

Comment: Thanks Man! That worked! Don't know why I din't try that.

Comment: On Windows XP and later, you don't need to manage the text manually like this if you have CommCtrl v6 Visual Styles enabled in your app.  You can use the [`EM_SETCUEBANNER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639.aspx) message instead and let Windows handle everything for you.